# Collapse SearchView (in ActionBar) on Back button press

Tags: android, searchview

I have implemented SearchView in ActionBar, But the problem with it is, whenever am typing something and press submit, the SearchView doesn't collapse back into that Search icon, it stays expanded, neither when I press Back button, SearchView doesn't collapse back.

My implementation is like this:

menu_search.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    item = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    int searchBarId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_bar", null, null);
    searchBar = searchView.findViewById(searchBarId);
    searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            item.collapseActionView();

            searchView.setQuery("", false);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            searchBar.clearFocus();

            .
            .
            .
            .
            .

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Things I have tried:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (item.isActionViewExpanded()) {
        item.collapseActionView();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

and

```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       super.onBackPressed();
       if (searchView != null) {
           searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
           searchView.setQuery("", false);
           searchView.clearFocus();
           searchBar.clearFocus();
           hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
       } else {
           super.onBackPressed();
       }
   }

   public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
       InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
               (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                       Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
               activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
```

SearchView expands from left to right to type but doesn't collapse back form right to left.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and let me know if it works.

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, ResultActivity.class)));
    searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
            searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                    searchView.clearFocus();
                    item.collapseActionView();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    searchView.clearFocus();
                    item.collapseActionView();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the second page of Google search and found this.
It worked for me.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    searchView.setIconified(true);
                }
            }
        });
```